# C# Memory Leaks with Fields or Member variables

Tags: c#

I have a object B which takes in a object C through it's constructor.
Now C is created inside the constructor of A and set as a Field/Member variable. 
Inside A I create multiple instances of B and insert them into an List. 
Later I clear this List......... my question is do I have a memory leak, as C is still alive in A and A is of course alive.

Thanks

Comment: this is like asking "do i have a broken leg?" by *calling* a dokter. Show some code please.

Comment: Have a look for yourself by using the [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273). To Measure is to Know.

Answer (score 4):

C# has automatic garbage collection, so the framework will find out when one of the objects is not used any more and it will free the memory of the unused object.

If you are asking whether object C is also de-allocated when you clear the list of Bs, my bet is that it won't happen, since you still have a reference to it via the property (field) of A.

Comment: I am asking if B is removed from memory.

Comment: @Andy if your objects don't contain native types, EVERY object will be removed by the GC.

Comment: @Andy, all the objects that are not referenced any more will be removed by the garbage collector. That is, if you have a reference to that list of Bs, they will not be de-allocated. If you have a reference to just one of the Bs, all the non-referenced ones will be de-allocated.